# Determine the minimum number of edges E* such that increase the capacity of all these edges leads to icnrease of max flow

Tags: algorithm, graph, network-flow

Given a network flow G(V,E). After we run FF algorithm and get a residual grpah Gf and a min-cut (S,T)

I want to know a minimum number of edges E′⊂ E such that increasing capacity of each e ∈ E by one unit will increase the max flow to val(f)+1. The algorithm should run in O(E*log(V)).

Here is my approach.

For each cross edge (u,v)

(1) Use BFS to find partial augmenting path s to u; and all partial augmenting path from v to t. If both such partial augmenting path exists. Then increase the (u,v) can make max flow increase by one.

If (1) is false,

There are few possibility

(a) In residual, source s has no outgoing edge

(b) In residual, sink t has no incoming edge.

(c) both of above happens

In case of (a), the min-cut has one set contains only source s. Find the shortest path from cross edge to t, this distance + 1 (the cross edge) will be our minimal. By using Dijlstra algorithm in O(E*log(V)) time

In case of (b), similarly, find the shortest path from a cross edge to t (let's say this cross edge is (u,v) and v in T, v to t is the shortest path for all cross edge), this distance + 1 + the distance of shortest path from s to u = minimal number of edges that increase all its capacity by one, leads to max flow increase by one

In case of (c), we need to look for a shortest path from s to t; we can apply Dijlstra algorithm in O(E*log(V)) time.

However, I think the above approach can achieve the goal but not very efficient (especially in dealing with case (2), it might not run in E*log(V) time).

Is there easier way of approaching?

Answer (score 0):

If capacities are integers then this seems reasonably straightforward.

From S use depth first search to find all of the nodes reachable from there using links with spare capacity. Put these nodes in a set and mark them.

From T use depth first search to find all of the nodes that can reach T using links with spare capacity. Mark these nodes differently.

Use breadth first search to find the shortest path from any node reachable from S to any node that can reach T. Start with the set of nodes reachable from S. At each stage look it see if any node that can reach T is a neighbour of a node in the current set. If so then you are finished. If not, then the set for the next stage is the set of neighbours of nodes in the current set that are not marked. Mark all of the nodes in the new set.

If the capacities are not integers, so that creating any flow does not give you a flow of capacity at least one, then I think you are in the land of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum-cost_flow_problem.